# word counting is giving different count than original count

Tags: java, android, cpu-word

I'm having a problem counting the number of words in a file. The approach that I am taking is when I see a space or a newLine then I know to count a word.

The problem is that if I have multiple lines between paragraphs then I ended up counting them as words also. If you look at the `readFile()` method you can see what I am doing.

Could you help me out and guide me in the right direction on how to fix this?

Example input file (including a blank line):

```
word word word
word word

word word word
```

I tried the below code and able to print the Number of words..

```
File file = new File("sample.txt");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
int count=0;
while(sc.hasNext()){
    sc.next();
    count++;
}
System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
```

But in some time it is giving the word count is different.I checked the word count in Ms Office and pro grammatical  value (The above code gives the wrong count of words as it counts all the styles, adjustments etc.)

How should I achieve this.

Any help would be grateful for me

Comment: what do you mean 'wrong word count'

Comment: for example in my document it having 20 words but it showing 26 instead of 20

Comment: in your algorithm strings like for example `" - "` will be treated as words, i'm not sure is office will do same

Answer (score 2):

Enclose your read, in this condition:

```
if(!Character.isWhitespace(sc.next().charAt(0)))
    count++
```

Or maybe even better:

```
if(!sc.next().isEmpty())
    count++
```

Answer (score 0):

How about checking, if `sc.next()` is an empty string? If it is a new line I would assume it would be "". Then if it is indeed a new line you've grabbed, don't increment count.